# Fire-and-forget command-line tool to send a Facebook message

Tags: gratis, facebook, command-line, xmpp, bash

I want to send a Facebook message with a single Linux command line, something like:

> xmppmsg joe@chat.facebook.com message.txt --myuser=nico@chat.facebook.com --mypass=yop

I must get the prompt back as soon as the message has been sent.
I must be able to use it in a bash script.
Is there such a tool?

Facebook does not work with [sendxmpp](https://github.com/lhost/sendxmpp/issues/10), [shell-xmpp-client](https://github.com/close2/shell-xmpp-client/issues/3), [CenterIM](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-835219-start-0.html).
A hack based on [libpurple](https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Libpurple) would be enough.

Comment: Not using anything like that myself, but maybe worth a look: [shell-xmpp-client](https://github.com/close2/shell-xmpp-client). Also see: [Commandline Jabber client](http://stackoverflow.com/q/170503/2533433) at SO.

Comment: Is the receiver always the same person? If so, he could set up a Facebool mail address.

Comment: @ComFreek: Unfortunately not. Also, sending by email results in "untrusted sender" warnings, which I want to avoid.